# Generators of $U(2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, unitary-matrices, quantum-computation

I'm reading a book on quantum computing. In the book it says that any linear optical element (represented by the set of unitary matrices $U(2)$) is equivalent to a combination of balanced phase shifters and beamsplitters. The matrix for a balanced phase shifter is

$B_{l}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1  \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$

The matrix for a phase shifter is

$P=\begin{pmatrix}
e^{i\phi} & 0 \\
0 & 1  \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$ or $P=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & e^{i\theta} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$

Is there any way I can prove this mathematically? i.e. $\forall A\in U(2)$, $A$ can be written as products of $B_{l}$ and $P$

Edit: Here's what I did before posting this question. I know that $U(2)$ is isomorphic to the semi-direct product of $U(1)$ and $SU(2)$. So I tried to construct those two groups using $B_{l}$ and $P$, but I feel like I'm overthinking.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Please present your thoughts and attempts to solve this question.

Comment: Every  few years someone invents a new discipline and the foundational part consists of giving new, ever more impressive names to elements of SU(2)

Comment: If you care only for the answer, in the [wikipedia page of Unitary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix) you can find about the general form of a 2x2 unitary matrix and some factorizations of it.

Comment: @AlexThem i did check the wikipedia page and I can understand the factorization. But why does every unitary matrix can be written in the way given in the webpage?

Comment: Not exactly what you are searching for but have a look here ([How do one show that the Pauli Matrices together with the Unit matrix form a basis in the space of complex 2 x 2 matrices?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/292102/how-do-one-show-that-the-pauli-matrices-together-with-the-unit-matrix-form-a-bas)), because you are working in quantum computing, maybe searching with pauli matrices as basis lead you somewhere. There are multiple stackexchange questions about them and what they can "create".

Comment: Or something like that maybe could help([How come the Pauli Matrices are the generators of SU(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212865/how-come-the-pauli-matrices-are-the-generators-of-su2))